# Spring boot OAuth successful login listener not triggering

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-boot, listener

Using Spring boot - After successfully authenticating with GitHub OAuth, the Audit listener is not being triggered.

```
public class AuthenticationListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(final InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
       System.out.println("+++++++ ================ ------------");
   }

}
```

Do I need to register it anywhere else? I have tried as suggested else where on Stackoverflow to create a @Bean, but this made no difference.

Full code https://github.com/DashboardHub/PipelineDashboard/tree/feature/178-login-github

**Update**

SecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")//.failureUrl("/login?error")
            .permitAll()
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    ;
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2")
ClientResourcesConfig github() {
    return new ClientResourcesConfig();
}

private Filter ssoFilter() {
    CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(ssoFilter(this.github(), "/login/github"));
    filter.setFilters(filters);
    return filter;
}

private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResourcesConfig client, String path) {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter githubFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            path);
    OAuth2RestTemplate githubTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(),
            oauth2ClientContext);
    githubFilter.setRestTemplate(githubTemplate);
    githubFilter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(
            client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId()));
    return githubFilter;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working by injecting the default ApplicationEventPublisher into your security config bean. Then setting this as the application event publisher on the processingfilter:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;    

...        

githubFilter.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
```

For some reason, the application event publisher on the filter is a NullEventPublisher by default.

Comment: This is the commit with the changes for anyone else who needs it https://github.com/DashboardHub/PipelineDashboard/commit/14e1ab03d21c3dbed22cd9dc57cb9a7bfaedca38

Comment: not directly related to the question, but nevertheless, sometimes one might want to trigger the event manually, and this is done using publishEvent() method of the injected ApplicationEventPublisher

Answer (score 0):

Use @Configuration annotation on AuthenticationListener class to register it in your application context.

**EDIT**

As I could not figure out why event wasn't fired, I present alternative solution for this problem. You have to create class that implements `AuthenticationSuccessHanddler` and implement its `onAuthenticationSuccess` method:

```
@Component(value="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    //implementation
    }
}
```

Then add it to your configuration like:

```
@Resource
private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        .loginPage("/login").and()
        .successHandler(getCustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
        .permitAll()
        ...
}

public CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler getCustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    return customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
}
```

It's not exactly what you wanted, but should solve your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are authorized in Spring Security Context? You can checking on one of your views (https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/spring-security-part-v-security-tags/) or on the Authentication object (you can access it from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`)

Comment: Thanks for link. Yes, definitely Authorised with OAuth2 (GitHub). Does OAuth make a difference?

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly - are you authorised in your Spring Security context? `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()` returns true? Please debug after logging process and check it.

Comment: I just checked again, it definitely returns true.

Comment: Try to listen to `AbstractAuthenticationEvent` and log each event class name you receive. I think that because you're using OAuth the application publishes `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` and not `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent`

Comment: I also tried to listen for AuthenticationSuccessEvent, but that also didn't trigger. I can try AbstractAuthenticationEvent

Comment: Ok, could you edit your post with configuration class then?

Comment: Sure, I have edited my post to include my SecurityConfig class, or are you referring to another Configuration class that I might be missing?

Comment: Listening for AbstractAuthenticationEvent did not work either :(. Thanks for your continual support :)

Comment: If you look at the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java `successfulAuthentication(...)` method, it seems like your `eventPublisher` is null. Based on the information you provided I have no idea why - but what you can try to do is implement `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. I edited my post with explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the updated post! The .and().successHandler() was not allowed there, after some research it went here .loginPage("/login").successHandler(this.authenticationSuccessHandler). However, I am afraid to say, CustomSuccessHandler still didn't trigger :(.

Comment: If you are authenticated in spring session (so you're logging in correctly) and still successHandler is not triggered - then i think I ran out of ideas. Look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java . `successfullAuthentication()` is called by `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` if you get authenticated correctly, and it invokes `onAuthenticationSuccess`. Please let us know when you figure out what your problem was!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will keep looking into the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent, listening for an AuthenticationSuccessEvent did the trick for me.
However, the listener is called twice: first one's event's Authentication is an UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, while the second one is an OAuth2Authentication